# Unable to query firestore collection on timestamp column

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have a Firestore database which contains a list of jobs in a "jobs" collection. Each job has an end date which is a "timestamp" data type. When I try to query using a where condition, I get no data back when using the react-native-firebase module.

[Snapshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjmAs.png)

Below is the code I'm using:

```
return db.collection('jobs')
    .where('end', '>=', new Date());
```

Also tried:

```
    .where('end', '>=', new Date().toISOString());
```

Is there a specific data type/format I must send the date value as for it to match?

When I use the standard web SDK from Firebase on my web app, the data comes back correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an issue with date conversion going across the React Native bridge, we've since fixed this and the fix will be part of the v3.1.0 release in the next day or so.

An example of date querying can be seen in our tests: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/tests/src/tests/firestore/collectionReferenceTests.js#L523

So you are querying correctly with `.where('end', '>=', new Date());`

Thanks